Adding Large Integers in C++
The question is:

In C++, the largest int value is 2147483647. so an integer larger than this cannot be stored and processed as an integer. Similarly, if the sum or product of two positive integers is greater than 2147483647, the result will be incorrect. One way to store and manipulate large integers is to store each individual digit of the number in an array. Write a program that inputs two positive integers of, at most, 20 digits and outputs the sum of the numbers. If the sum of numbers has more than 20 digits, output the sum with an appropriate message.

I keep getting an output with some random numbers after I input the numbers, for example.
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n1[20] , n2[20] ;
    int sum[21];
    int carry = 0;
    char x1[21], x2[21];
    cout << "Enter the first integer(at most 20 digits): ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "Enter the second integer(at most 20 digits): ";
    cin >> x2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        n1[i] = x1[i] - '0';
        n2[i] = x2[i] - '0';
    }
    for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            sum[i] = n1[i - 1] + n2[i - 1] + carry;
            if (sum[i] > 9)
            {
                carry = 1;
                sum[i] = sum[i] - 10;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (carry != 0)
            {
                sum[i] = carry;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    sum[j] = sum[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The sum of the two integers is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        cout << sum[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

I am trying to figure out the issue for the output, and how to fix it as stated above (a guide would be nice as well for dealing with C-string for arrays).
What is the solution to this issue, and is there a mistake somewhere?

Your code assumes that both numbers contain exactly 20 digits. You need to take into account how many digits there really are in each one (and they may not be the same length).

"in C++, the largest int value is 2147483647" Sure, on a 8 bit microcontroller from the 1990s era. More high end CPUs tend to support 64 bit numbers even if they aren't 64 bit CPUs.

Anyway, implementing "big int" types in the most straight-forward way is to take input as strings and store them as strings too.

Aside from the fact that your numbers don't necessarily have matching lengths, or aren't exactly 20 digits -- I'd completely ditch the first loop, and just do -'0' and +'0' as needed to work on the strings directly.

I opened the question before there was even a comment and pondered this whole time how to comment without sounding harsh, so I am sorry for saying: honestly, it is not only the first loop that needs to be deleted, the rest of your code has problems too. Restart from scratch with std::string as was suggested by Lundin. Example: inside the for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) loop, first thing you do is if (i != 0) -> then why don't you do for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--), remove that if and move the else outside of the for? And the rest would be better if changed too.

When the output is surprising, it's usually a good idea to verify that your inputs are what you expect instead of just assuming that they are. Try printing the elements of  n1 and n2 after that first setup loop.

If you input 12 and 3, what is the answer that your program should give? Explain by showing how each digit of the answer is computed.

2147483647 is maximum value of int32_t. So use int64_t if you need bigger integers. Then the maximum is 9223372036854775807. Having integers bigger than that often indicates some rather niche problem (worth mentioning) or programming error.

If you need arbitrarily big numbers, use gnu gmp https://gmplib.org/

There are gnu libraries ready for you to do maths on infinitely large digit numbers
